# Count occurrence of words in multiple files

Tags: python, unix

I have a list of genes that looks like this and its called miRs.txt

```
miRs
miR-92|LQNS02278089.1_34108
miR-92|LQNS02278089.1_34106
miR-92|LQNS02278089.1_34110
miR-184|LQNS02000211.1_1952
miR-184|LQNS02000211.1_1954
miR-184|LQNS02000211.1_1795
miR-184|LQNS02000211.1_1950
bantam|LQNS02278082.1_33125
miR-1|LQNS02277099.1_24575
```

each line is a unique gene name and there are 176 total names.
I also have 32 other txt where each file is a different specie and in each row I got the genes that are present.
This is an example for two files called daphnia_pulex.txt and daphnia_magna.txt, I got other 30 files that I would like to process the same way.

```
cat daphnia_pulex
qseqid
miR-92|LQNS02278089.1_34108
miR-92|LQNS02278089.1_34106
miR-92|LQNS02278089.1_34110
miR-184|LQNS02000211.1_1952
miR-184|LQNS02000211.1_1954
bantam|LQNS02278082.1_33125

cat daphnia_magna.txt
qseqid
miR-92|LQNS02278089.1_34106
miR-92|LQNS02278089.1_34110
miR-184|LQNS02000211.1_1795
miR-184|LQNS02000211.1_1950
bantam|LQNS02278082.1_33125
miR-1|LQNS02277099.1_24575
```

Ideally I want an output that looks like this:

[image]

I know ho two do this using grep

```
grep -wc "miR-92|LQNS02278089.1_34108" *.txt
```

but that requires me to type each gene name every time. 
If you could please help me !
Thanks.

Comment: Done, in case it can help someone I created a csv file with all the hits per organism and then  I tried this and worked.
```a <- data %>% 
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -miRs) %>% 
    filter(value != "") %>% 
    count(name, value) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
```

Comment: You can answer your own question and format the code properly in there.  Code in comments is notoriously difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

Done, in case it can help someone I created a csv file with all the hits per organism and then I tried this and worked.

```
a <- data %>% 
type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
pivot_longer(cols = -miRs) %>% 
filter(value != "") %>% count(name, value) %>% 
pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
```